# Server-sent events on Azure with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, azure, jersey, tomcat8, server-sent-events

I have a Jersey app deployed on a local Tomcat 8. Server-sent events work fine while running on localhost or on my self-hosted Ubuntu server.

Running the same app on a Tomcat 8 app service in Microsoft Azure breaks the server-sent events. I don't receive any events, the connection will timeout with a 503 after some time.

I'm new to Azure, do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you enable the `always-on` option on Azure WebApp? "Server-sent events is similar to the long-polling mechanism" as jersey offical document said, I doubt your app sit idle for too long that cause Azure broke the server-sent events, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-web-sites-adds-always-on/ to know this case.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Unfortunately I tried that already with no luck. I don't even get the first chunk which is sent immediately after opening of the connection.

Comment: Does this matter? As far as I know, the SSE Client should handle automatically the reconnection, so your program should work both when there is a single, long-term connection, or when multiple reconnections occur.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. But it was worth a try. I'm using long-polling for now but would still be interested in a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Paul, I have the same issue. works well on `localhost` but failed on `azurewebapp`. Did you figure how it?

Comment: Facing the same issue , any thoughts about this?

Comment: Azure does not support server-sent events. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/34093603-support-server-sent-events